# How to use an Amazon EBS volume to serve web content using Apache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

How do you actually USE an Amazon EBS volume?

I've created an EC2 instance with an Apache web server and PHP but, as storage in EC2 is ephemeral, I've attached an EBS volume to it. The volume has been mounted and I have been able to upload a 'hello world' HTML file to the volume.

So far so good, but I can't find any mention anywhere of how to access the file with a browser!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EBS provides you block storage solution. When you attach an EBS volume into your EC2 instance, AWS just provide to your VM another volume, for example, **2nd volume**.

Apache web server, which serves as your backend service, it will store your web directory at somewhere, usually in **root volume**.

Then, you just need to copy files from **2nd volume** into your **root volume**.

**For Linux:**

List your current disk space usage, it will show the mountpoint as well

```
df -h
```

For example, your files are located in mountpoint `/mnt` which is the 2nd volume, you want to copy into the main web directory which is located in `/etc/php-fpm/mydomain.com/`.

```
cp /mnt/index.php /etc/php-fpm/mydomain.com/
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use the EBS volume for backup storage, I want to use it as the active website.

Comment: @DorianFabre 2nd volume here is not a backup storage, it's that EC2's volume as well. As I said, it's up to your Apache Web Server's main directory location. If you want the main directory to be placed in the 2nd volume, then you need to know how to configure it on the 2nd volume.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I had to do to get the EC2 server to point to the EBS volume:

1. Edit the **httpd.conf** file with Nano in PuTTy: `sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
2. Find & replace `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"` with `DocumentRoot "/EBS_MOUNT_POINT"`
3. Find & replace `<Directory "/var/www">` with `DocumentRoot <Directory "/EBS_MOUNT_POINT">`
4. Find & replace `<Directory "/var/www/html">` with `DocumentRoot <Directory "/EBS_MOUNT_POINT">`
5. Save & close Nano
6. Restart the web server service: `sudo service httpd restart`

And it works!